# Trouble with Glassfish Server and ActiveMQ: peer did not send his wire format

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, activemq-classic

I'm getting this error while trying to set up a JMSPublisher and JMSSubscriber

**jndi.properties**

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = tcp://localhost:4848?wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=30000
topic.topic/flightStatus = flightStatus
```

Glassfish server is running on: `http://localhost:4848`

**Publisher:**

```java
JmsPublisher publisher= new JmsPublisher("ConnectionFactory", "topic/flightStatus");

...

public JmsPublisher(String factoryName, String topicName) throws JMSException, NamingException {
    Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
    TopicConnectionFactory factory = (TopicConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(factoryName);
    Topic topic = (Topic) jndiContext.lookup(topicName);
    this.connect = factory.createTopicConnection();
    this.session = connect.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    this.publisher = session.createPublisher(topic);
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1395)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1481)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:323)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createTopicSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:1112)
    at com.mycompany.testejms.JmsPublisher.<init>(JmsPublisher.java:34)
    at com.mycompany.testejms.JmsPublisher.main(JmsPublisher.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:98)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1366)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual stack-trace for the exception you're seeing?

Comment: Also, please provide the configuration for the connection factory you're looking up from JNDI, specifically the URL used.

Comment: the JNDI configuration file and the stack-trace were added. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I changed the server port to 61616 and now i'm getting this:  Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=30000. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35)
 at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:293)
 at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:238)

Comment: When you say that you "changed the server port to 61616" do you mean that you're using `tcp://localhost:61616` in the value of `java.naming.provider.url` in your `jndi.properties`? If so, did you actually confirm that your ActiveMQ instance is listening on port `61616`? The `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` indicates that the client can't connect. Likely causes are that ActiveMQ isn't actually listening on that port or perhaps there's a firewall blocking communication.

Comment: @JustinBertram, i changed in jndi.properties, but it turns out that aparently i do not have ActiveMq installed on my computer.Thanks for your help and yout time

Comment: @JustinBertram, thanks a lot, i installed ActiveMQ and now everything works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the ActiveMQ client is not actually communicating with an ActiveMQ broker. Glassfish may be listening on `http://localhost:4848`, but apparently that's not where the ActiveMQ broker is listening for connections. From what I understand, port `4848` is where the Glassfish web admin console listens for connections. Note the `http` in the URL you provided. By default, ActiveMQ listens on port `61616`.